# How to test Windows library under different user-security permutations?

Tags: windows, security, testing

I am working on a developer library that I want to release later this year and it should work under different user rights and also on different windows platforms. The library can be executed in both a web, windows-service and desktop-app-client context.

What combinations of users should I test the application under? Is it enough to test it using

1. Normal standard user
2. Administrator
3. Local system account

Are there any more permutations of users? What kind of typical users/policies do exists out in the enterprises?

Are there any guides about how to Windows "test" software before release so that the number of security/rights gotchas/issues can be addressed before the application hit the customers?